# What is the difference between khilafa and wilaya?

Tags: quran, hadith, sharia, khilafah

I would like to know the difference  Between a wilaya and a khilafa, since both have a leader who should be listened and obeyed as long as they are muslim and both of them rule over a specific landmass,